# Broadcast Receiver onReceive not getting intent bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm sending a text (pre-kit kat) using the below code.  When I create the intent to be passed into the smsManager, I put an int extra into the intent.  in the broadcast receiver when I call intent.getIntExtra, it just keeps giving me a value of 0.  Any ideas why?

when I print the value of i in the onReceive to the log, it shows the value is 0 every time

Here's the sending code (this is in a for loop, so "i" can be anything from 0 - 10):

```
for (int i = 0; i < getSelectedNumbers().size(); i++) {
            Log.d("Pete Debug", "Loop value of i = " + String.valueOf(i));

            String number = removeSpecialCharacters(getSelectedNumbers().get(i));
            String smsSending = "Sending to " + number + "... ";
            Log.d("Pete Debug", smsSending);

            statusItems = new SmsStatusItems();
            statusItems.setMessage(smsSending);
            statusItems.setImage(R.drawable.clock);
            smsStatusAdapter.add(statusItems);

            Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SMS_SENT);
            sentIntent.putExtra(SMS_SENT, i);

            Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED);
            deliveredIntent.putExtra(SMS_DELIVERED, i);

            mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, getFinalMessage(),
                    (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, sentIntent, 0)),
                    (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, deliveredIntent, 0)));
        }
```

and here's the broadcast receiver:

```
smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int i = intent.getIntExtra(SMS_SENT, -1);
        Log.d("Pete Debug", "Sent value of i = " + i);

        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                smsStatusAdapter.getItem(i).setImage(R.drawable.pass);
                smsStatusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                smsStatusAdapter.getItem(i).setImage(R.drawable.fail);
                smsStatusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                smsStatusAdapter.getItem(i).setImage(R.drawable.fail);
                smsStatusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                smsStatusAdapter.getItem(i).setImage(R.drawable.fail);
                smsStatusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                smsStatusAdapter.getItem(i).setImage(R.drawable.fail);
                smsStatusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: "i" is an int in a for loop, it's any int between 0 and 10.  and what's that other thing you need?  See my edits

Comment: From the PendingIntent documentation: "A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time."
I think what happens is that you're really only creating one PendingIntent, which you're retrieving over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should add `FILL_IN_DATA` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag:

```
  mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, getFinalMessage(),
                    (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, sentIntent,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)),
                    (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, deliveredIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)));
```

and wait for the SMS to be received (`RESULT_OK`) before sending another one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getSelectedNumbers().size(); i++) {
            Log.d("Pete Debug", "Loop value of i = " + String.valueOf(i));

            String number = removeSpecialCharacters(getSelectedNumbers().get(i));
            String smsSending = "Sending to " + number + "... ";
            Log.d("Pete Debug", smsSending);

            statusItems = new SmsStatusItems();
            statusItems.setMessage(smsSending);
            statusItems.setImage(R.drawable.clock);
            smsStatusAdapter.add(statusItems);

            Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SMS_SENT);
            sentIntent.putExtra(SMS_SENT, i);

            Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED);
            deliveredIntent.putExtra(SMS_DELIVERED, i);


            // This for waiting ;) put the other code here
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));




            mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, getFinalMessage(),
                            (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, sentIntent,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)),
                            (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, deliveredIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA)));
            }
```

Comment: put more code about your i changes and boucle.. so the value is the same "0"?

Comment: I really wish it did.  but no.  trying FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT now

Comment: ok, update_current gave us some progress.  Still not working, but instead of everything returning a value of 0 in onReceive, it's now all returning a value of the highest value of i

Comment: Thats why: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT you was sending the first value "0" now with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT update it till the last one

Comment: Thanks for the words, happy that was helful for you sir :D

Answer (score 1):

One event - one shot

```
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    res_int, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```